# Unexpected EOF in PHP code block

Tags: php, pdo

I have a block of code that gives the unexpected EOF (end of file) error. I just can't find it.

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute([

```
        $query = "UPDATE images SET 
        `filename`= :filename,
        `display_start_date`= :display_start_date,
        `display_end_date` = :display_end_date,
        `display_delay` = :display_delay;

            $pdoResult =  $pdo->prepare($query);                               
            $pdoExecute = $pdoResult->execute(
            [
                ':name'               => $imageName,
                ':path'               => $path;
                ':filename'           => $imageFilename,
                ':display_start_date' => $displayStartDate,
                ':display_end_date'   => $displayEndDate,
                ':display_delay'      => $displayDelay,
                ':upload_date'        => date('Y-m-d'),
                ':image_id'           => $imageId)
            ]
            )
        }
```

More PHP comes after this so I do not need a ?>.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you missing the quotation mark after `:display_delay;`?

Answer (score 0):

are you closing the quotes for this line?
`$query = "UPDATE images SET`

```
    $query = "UPDATE images SET 
    `filename`= :filename,
    `display_start_date`= :display_start_date,
    `display_end_date` = :display_end_date,
    `display_delay` = :display_delay";
```